# How to perform checks on incoming messages in Biztalk orchestrations

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I am receiving a message from CRM in my Biztalk orchestration and that message contains one field called "Status" in it. Now I want my Orchestration to complete rest of the operations only if the status field is populated otherwise it should end. I know that we can use decide shape for decision making, but how do I check if the status field is populated or not to make decision? I have added the images of schema and orchestration.

[image: Orchestration]

[image: Schema].

Searched on google and found nothing useful

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Comment: Would promoting the status field be an option?. Use it as 'property of your message' (e.g. IncomingMessage.Status) in the decide shape.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Biztalk is not allowing distinguish fields on status since it can occur multiple times.

Comment: Correct, distinguished or promoted fields can only occur once.   How are you trying to make a decision on something that occurs more that once?

Comment: Can you explain the logic you want, e.g. what if one of the Status nodes has a value, and others do not?

Comment: We did a workaround. We introduced a new API which will return Yes or No depending on which the orchestration will process further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did a workaround. We introduced a new API which will return Yes or No depending on which the orchestration will process further.

Answer (score 0):

In your map, have a Logical Exist or Logical String functoid that checks for a value, and have a Scripting functoid set a value in your destination schema to True or False.  That way it will exist and you can use it in your decision shape.

If as per your comments, the status field occurs more than once, you either need to use XPath expressions that evaluate multiple nodes, or have some logic in the mapping that uses the iteration functoid to just look at a particular node instance.